# Qt:Headers And Libraries Not Found

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, fedora, configure

I am trying to install `korundum` on fedora 17. And during the `./configure` phase I got the following error:

```
checking for Qt... configure: error: Qt (>= Qt 3.3 and < 4.0) (headers and libraries) not found. Please check your installation!
```

Now I guess I have QT installed and I tried to do the following:

```
./configure --with-qt-includes=/usr/lib64/qt4/include
```

but that did not work either
So what should I do... for you info I am listing below the output of:

```
yum list *-devel | grep -i qt


qt-devel.x86_64                       1:4.8.4-1.fc17                    @updates
qtwebkit-devel.x86_64                 2.2.2-1.fc17                      @updates
ruby-qt-devel.x86_64                  4.9.4-1.fc17                      @updates
OpenSceneGraph-qt-devel.i686          3.0.1-13.fc17                     updates 
OpenSceneGraph-qt-devel.x86_64        3.0.1-13.fc17                     updates 
PackageKit-qt-devel.i686              0.7.5-1.fc17                      updates 
PackageKit-qt-devel.x86_64            0.7.5-1.fc17                      updates 
PyQt-devel.i686                       3.18.1-11.fc17                    fedora  
PyQt-devel.x86_64                     3.18.1-11.fc17                    fedora  
PyQt4-devel.i686                      4.9.1-2.fc17                      fedora  
PyQt4-devel.x86_64                    4.9.1-2.fc17                      fedora  
SoQt-devel.i686                       1.5.0-5.fc17                      fedora  
SoQt-devel.x86_64                     1.5.0-5.fc17                      fedora  
avahi-qt3-devel.i686                  0.6.31-5.fc17                     updates 
avahi-qt3-devel.x86_64                0.6.31-5.fc17                     updates 
avahi-qt4-devel.i686                  0.6.31-5.fc17                     updates 
avahi-qt4-devel.x86_64                0.6.31-5.fc17                     updates 
bamf-qt-devel.i686                    0.2.3-1.fc17                      fedora  
bamf-qt-devel.x86_64                  0.2.3-1.fc17                      fedora  
dbus-qt3-devel.i686                   0.9-8.fc17                        fedora  
dbus-qt3-devel.x86_64                 0.9-8.fc17                        fedora  
dbusmenu-qt-devel.i686                0.9.0-3.fc17                      fedora  
dbusmenu-qt-devel.x86_64              0.9.0-3.fc17                      fedora  
ibus-qt-devel.i686                    1.3.1-8.fc17                      fedora  
ibus-qt-devel.x86_64                  1.3.1-8.fc17                      fedora  
kdevelop-pg-qt-devel.i686             1.0.0-1.fc17                      fedora  
kdevelop-pg-qt-devel.x86_64           1.0.0-1.fc17                      fedora  
libQtGTL-devel.i686                   0.9.2-1.fc17                      fedora  
libQtGTL-devel.x86_64                 0.9.2-1.fc17                      fedora  
libaccounts-qt-devel.i686             0.31-5.fc17                       fedora  
libaccounts-qt-devel.x86_64           0.31-5.fc17                       fedora  
libircclient-qt-devel.i686            0.5.0-4.fc17                      fedora  
libircclient-qt-devel.x86_64          0.5.0-4.fc17                      fedora  
libmygpo-qt-devel.i686                1.0.5-3.fc17                      fedora  
libmygpo-qt-devel.x86_64              1.0.5-3.fc17                      fedora  
libprojectM-qt-devel.i686             2.0.1-5.fc17                      fedora  
libprojectM-qt-devel.x86_64           2.0.1-5.fc17                      fedora  
libqttracker-devel.i686               6.11.0-2.fc15                     fedora  
libqttracker-devel.x86_64             6.11.0-2.fc15                     fedora  
lightdm-qt-devel.i686                 1.2.3-1.fc17                      updates 
lightdm-qt-devel.x86_64               1.2.3-1.fc17                      updates 
perl-Qt-devel.i686                    0.96.0-2.fc17                     fedora  
perl-Qt-devel.x86_64                  0.96.0-2.fc17                     fedora  
plplot-qt-devel.i686                  5.9.9-6.svn12161.fc17             fedora  
plplot-qt-devel.x86_64                5.9.9-6.svn12161.fc17             fedora  
polkit-qt-devel.i686                  0.103.0-2.fc17                    fedora  
polkit-qt-devel.x86_64                0.103.0-2.fc17                    fedora  
poppler-qt-devel.i686                 0.18.4-3.fc17                     fedora  
poppler-qt-devel.x86_64               0.18.4-3.fc17                     fedora  
python3-PyQt4-devel.i686              4.9.1-2.fc17                      fedora  
python3-PyQt4-devel.x86_64            4.9.1-2.fc17                      fedora  
qt-assistant-adp-devel.i686           4.6.3-3.fc17                      fedora  
qt-assistant-adp-devel.x86_64         4.6.3-3.fc17                      fedora  
qt-devel.i686                         1:4.8.4-1.fc17                    updates 
qt-gstreamer-devel.i686               0.10.2-1.fc17                     fedora  
qt-gstreamer-devel.x86_64             0.10.2-1.fc17                     fedora  
qt-mobility-devel.i686                1.2.0-10.20110922.fc17            fedora  
qt-mobility-devel.x86_64              1.2.0-10.20110922.fc17            fedora  
qt-qsa-devel.i686                     1.1.5-9.fc17                      fedora  
qt-qsa-devel.x86_64                   1.1.5-9.fc17                      fedora  
qt3-devel.i686                        3.3.8b-41.fc17                    fedora  
qt3-devel.x86_64                      3.3.8b-41.fc17                    fedora  
qtiocompressor-devel.i686             2.3.1-3.fc17                      fedora  
qtiocompressor-devel.x86_64           2.3.1-3.fc17                      fedora  
qtlockedfile-devel.i686               2.4-4.fc17                        fedora  
qtlockedfile-devel.x86_64             2.4-4.fc17                        fedora  
qtsingleapplication-devel.i686        2.6.1-6.fc17                      fedora  
qtsingleapplication-devel.x86_64      2.6.1-6.fc17                      fedora  
qtsinglecoreapplication-devel.i686    2.6.1-6.fc17                      fedora  
qtsinglecoreapplication-devel.x86_64  2.6.1-6.fc17                      fedora  
qtsoap-devel.i686                     2.7-3.fc17                        fedora  
qtsoap-devel.x86_64                   2.7-3.fc17                        fedora  
qtwebkit-devel.i686                   2.2.2-1.fc17                      updates 
qtweetlib-devel.i686                  0.5-1.fc17                        fedora  
qtweetlib-devel.x86_64                0.5-1.fc17                        fedora  
qwtplot3d-qt4-devel.i686              0.2.7-10.fc15                     fedora  
qwtplot3d-qt4-devel.x86_64            0.2.7-10.fc15                     fedora  
ruby-qt-devel.i686                    4.9.4-1.fc17                      updates 
simfqt-devel.i686                     1.00.0-1.fc17                     updates 
simfqt-devel.x86_64                   1.00.0-1.fc17                     updates 
smokeqt-devel.i686                    4.9.4-1.fc17                      updates 
smokeqt-devel.x86_64                  4.9.4-1.fc17                      updates 
telepathy-logger-qt-devel.i686        0.5.2-1.fc17                      updates 
telepathy-logger-qt-devel.x86_64      0.5.2-1.fc17                      updates 
telepathy-qt4-devel.i686              0.9.3-2.fc17                      updates 
telepathy-qt4-devel.x86_64            0.9.3-2.fc17                      updates 
zbar-qt-devel.i686                    0.10-11.fc17                      fedora  
zbar-qt-devel.x86_64                  0.10-11.fc17                      fedora  
zint-qt-devel.i686                    2.4.3-3.fc17                      fedora  
zint-qt-devel.x86_64                  2.4.3-3.fc17                      fedora
```

So, how can I install Qt4 headers and libraries on fedora 17? How can solve this problem.

Comment: If I'm reading that message right, it actually wants the Qt _three_ libraries.  If that's the case, a simple `yum install qt3 qt3-devel` should fix it.